# Assign IP address to Apache Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I installed an Apache Tomcat 8.20 Server. When I pinged my-ip-address:8080 in the browser, I see the Tomcat setup page.

However, I'm having trouble assigning an IP address given by my IT administrator to listen to Tomcat.

For example, my local machine's IP is `10.60.80.2:8080`. My IT administrator freed this IP address (firewall on): `10.60.80.5:8030`. It's on the same server.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the ip address is working in your server then check the configuration for the HTTP connector in `conf/server.xml` inside the tomcat directory, there you can modify the ip address and the port where tomcat will listen, or you can add a new connector:

```
<Connector port="8030"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           address="10.60.80.5"
/>
```

Comment: Do i need to create 2 connectors for 2 ports?

Comment: I tried,its saying web page cannot be found.HTTP 400 bad request

Comment: Two connectors will work. Are you sure the ip address is properly configured on the server?

Comment: yes i also did: telnet 10.60.80.5 8030 and its working,cannot understand the problem.the PORT is open

Comment: some things you could check: if tomcat is stopped the port 8030 is still open? , where are you getting the error 400, from a machine on the same network or browsing in the same server?

Comment: Yes, I stopped Tomcat and ip was still accessible ..what does this mean.

Comment: I think you should review the issue with your IT Administrator , maybe some configuration on the network is not working properly.

Comment: Is it possible to listen via AJP connector?

Comment: Yes, but you will need apache with mod_jk in front of tomcat.

Comment: Dear HD,thanks, Solved it as above code.The problem was by assigning ip,its was done based on IIS .and port and ip was in use.